# GPU Frequecy Scaling Indicator

Tags: ati, gpu

I have ATI radeon 6320 graphics. As **cpu** frequency scaling indicator is there any **gpu** frequency scaling indicator? Where i can set possible **gpu clock** speed or mode (performance, power-saving,etc).

Note: I am not talking about **over-clocking** of GPU.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rovclock tool can be use but unfortunately my APU's over-clocking feature is disable by manufacture for safety issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old question but someone might find this solution useful.

From `/etc/default/tlp`:

```
# Radeon graphics clock speed (profile method): low, mid, high, auto, default;
# auto = mid on BAT, high on AC; default = use hardware defaults.
# (Kernel >= 2.6.35 only, open-source radeon driver explicitly)
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=default
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low

# Radeon dynamic power management method (DPM): battery, performance
# (Kernel >= 3.11 only, requires boot option radeon.dpm=1)
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery

# Radeon DPM performance level: auto, low, high; auto is recommended.
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
```

`dmesg` could be one way to check the actual frequencies.

```
sudo apt install tlp
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
sudo tlp start
```